# Duplicating HTML elements and the contents within in the HTML document

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have the following code:

```
      <div id="Car1Container">
        <label id="Car1YearLabel" for="Car1Year">Year</label>
        <input id="Car1Year" name="Car1Year" type="text" maxlength="4" onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)" onkeydown="FieldOnKeyDown(this)" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)" onblur="FieldOnBlur(this)"/>
        <label id="Car1MakeLabel" for="Car1Make">Make</label>
        <input id="Car1Make" name="Car1Make" type="text" maxlength="15" onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)" onkeydown="FieldOnKeyDown(this)" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)" onblur="FieldOnBlur(this)"/>
        <label id="Car1ModelLabel" for="Car1Model">Model</label>
        <input id="Car1Model" name="Car1Model" type="text" maxlength="16" onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)" onkeydown="FieldOnKeyDown(this)" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)" onblur="FieldOnBlur(this)"/>
        <button id="AddVehicleButton1" name="AddVehicleButton1" type="button" onclick="AddVehicle()">Add Vehicle</button>
      </div>
      <div id="Car2Container" style = "display: none;">
        <label id="Car2YearLabel" for="Car2Year">Year</label>
        <input id="Car2Year" name="Car2Year" type="text" maxlength="4" onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)" onkeydown="FieldOnKeyDown(this)" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)" onblur="FieldOnBlur(this)"/>
        <label id="Car2MakeLabel" for="Car2Make">Make</label>
        <input id="Car2Make" name="Car2Make" type="text" maxlength="15" onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)" onkeydown="FieldOnKeyDown(this)" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)" onblur="FieldOnBlur(this)"/>
        <label id="Car2ModelLabel" for="Car2Model">Model</label>
        <input id="Car2Model" name="Car2Model" type="text" maxlength="16" onfocus="FieldOnFocus(this)" onkeydown="FieldOnKeyDown(this)" onkeyup="FieldOnKeyUp(this)" onblur="FieldOnBlur(this)"/>
        <button id="AddVehicleButton2" name="AddVehicleButton2" type="button" onclick="AddVehicle2()">Add Vehicle</button>
      </div>
```

Currently, AddVehicle() just changes the Car2Container style to 'block'. I have a finite number of these and I want it to be dynamic. I have some code to attempt to write it to a page, but it erases everything on the page and doesn't really work.

I want to write an AddVehicle() function to duplicate the Car1Container and place it right below in the HTML document (except all the 1s become 2s). This is turning out to be quite a challenge! Can anyone help get me moving in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: Regex? Why do you have a regex label? Also, where are you at with your attempts (post your code)?

Comment: does this have to be added dynamically, can you have all of this on your page at runtime and then just show it when need be? I think that may be an easier solution for you if that fits your needs?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I will post what I'm doing now momentarily.

Comment: @DylanHayes: That's what I'm doing now. I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cloneNode(true)](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode) for cloning the block, then go through [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes) property to find all the children (maybe recursively) and replace their ids and names.

**Added:** Here's a working example:

```
var container = document.getElementById('Car1Container'); 
var copy = container.cloneNode(true); 
container.parentNode.appendChild(copy);
```

Comment: It may not happen this time, but you're bound to get downvoted for linking to w3schools on SO. See: http://w3fools.com

Comment: That could work. I only have one number in each ID and I could use a regex to increment it. But how do I use cloneNode() to copy the entire div into the HTML document below?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: TIL. Thanks, changed links to MDN.

Comment: Awesome. Let me play with it awhile. If I can get everything to work, I'll come back and give you credit for the answer.

Comment: The only issue I'm having is incrementing the '1's. How would you go about replacing all the 1s in the copied container with '2's. I can declare a variable that increases/decreases correctly based on which button is clicked, but how can I substitute the value of that variable where the '1's are in the original container? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Mike: Fast and dirty: http://pastebin.com/uWGMijSS . However, I personally would construct whole block dynamically with jQuery. What I mean that instead of cloning the original node, I'd create it from scratch with javascript.

Comment: I agree with dynamically adding it. That seems like the way to go. I'm trying that way now and will let you know if I get results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jquery you can just do:

```
var index = 1;
function copycar(){
 index++;
 var $tmp = $("#Car1Container").clone();
 $tmp.children().each(function(){
   var oldID = $("this").attr("id");
   var newId = oldId.substring(0,3)+index+oldId.substring(4);
   $(this).attr("id", newId);
 }
 $("#Car1Container").after($tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery [Clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) will do this rather nicely. Granted, it won't increase the ID's, but I'm not convinced it needs to. Just name the fields CarYear, CarMake etc. When the values are posted to the server, if you've duplicated three of the div's, they'll be comma-separated. If necessary, you could iterate through the items and change the id's manually.

Answer (score 0):

Without using `jQuery`, just raw JavaScript you could use `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Example:
d`ocument.getElementById(‘ID’).insertAdjacentHTML(position, markup)`

where position can be "`beforebegin`", "`afterbegin`", "`beforeend`", or "`afterend`"

http://lionheart.sg/insertadjacenthtml/

This should be faster than the clone method in `jQuery`.

Comment: That's interesting… It doesn't display the second one for me though. What should be the value for markup?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [jquery clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function would be useful for this.